# Internet Explorer Css variable content dynamically

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Please I try to make the content of the pseudo class of element dynamically, it works fine with ( Google Chrome, Firefox, safari ).

**Css:**

```
.list-rank > li:before{
    content: var(--rank ,'0')
}
```

**HTML**

```
for (var i = 0; i <res.data.rankListUser.length; i++) {
  html +='<li style="--rank:\''+res.data.rankListUser[i].rank+'\'" >';
  html +='name here'
  html +='</li>';
} 
$('#ranking_container').html(html);
```

Comment: IE does not support CSS variables.

Comment: Any alternatives please to make the same result, thank you.

Comment: You could potentially use `attr(data-value)` as there is support for that in the `content` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE does not support CSS variables like these, but you could potentially use a `data` attribute:

```css
div:before { content: attr(data-word); }
```

```html
<div data-word="Hello">World</div>
```

This will *only* work with the `content` property, though - it cannot be used to set colors etc... At least not currently, which means for IE it's probably a never. According to MDN this is supported on IE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr